# Does there exist a projective CAS calculator?

Tags: projective-geometry, calculator

I'm sorry if the question isn't strictly related to maths but I really can't seem to find anything good and I don't where to ask.

Just to see some projective curves I thought to search for a Graphic Calculator programmed for projective planes. However I couldn't find anything and I'm stuck with some really bad simulations in Geogebra3D that also get usually stuck with curves with more branches.

Does there exist something like that?

Comment: Don’t really know of any, but for curves in ${\Bbb P}^2_{\Bbb R}$ some engine like the geogebra 3d one could use $S^2$ in ${\Bbb R}^3,$ like in [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Parabola_%26_cubic_curve_in_projective_space.png).

Comment: Yeah yeah, I tried to construct something like that but there are still problems such as identifying opposite points and some intersections just don't work (due to software things I don't get). Plus I think that a calculator built just for that purpose would be cleaner and easier to use

Answer (score 2):

[My try](https://www.geogebra.org/m/u4fnupj9).

Since geogebra can't really intersect, you can only sort of see the cusp of intersecting $z=x^3/y^2$ with the unit sphere. Also, similarly, solving the quadratic in $z$ and allowing both signs, you get the curve $y^2z-(x^3-xz^2)=0.$

These tricks only work for low degree...

Another idea would be to be able to [move the line at infinity](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/wp7wvaw6). This has the advantage of being useful for a general homogenous equation in $x,y,z,$ just change the definition of `h(x,y,z)`. (Maybe the moving infinity line in ${\Bbb P}^2$ (plane in ${\Bbb R}^3$) should be given differently in the above implementation?)

[Take III](https://www.geogebra.org/m/tjwrempa).

Comment: @OrazioCherubini See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

[Cinderella](https://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php) is a dynamic geometry software that has a projective approach. It looks like many others programs for euclidean geometry but internally it works with homogeneous coordinates in the projective plane, and even has a spherical view to include the line at infinity.